# Permission Error in VS Code When Saving File on Network Drive Shared - How to Resolve

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, permissions, network-drive

I'm running a local server in my network, powered by Ubuntu 22.04, that shares a folder with all stations.

I've installed a VPN using ZeroTier to access this local server from anywhere.

Everything seems to be working perfectly, except when I open a folder in VS Code and try to save a file, I encounter a permission error.

Here's the error message I receive:

```
Failed to save '.env.example': Command failed: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code.cmd" --file-write "c:\Users\feedc\AppData\Roaming\Code\code-elevated-zTqUa1mg" "\\192.168.196.241\storage\repos\node.js\airbnb-auto-email\.env.example"
Error using --file-write: EPERM: operation not permitted, open '\\192.168.196.241\storage\repos\node.js\airbnb-auto-email\.env.example'
```

What puzzles me is that the network drive functions correctly when I'm using Sublime or when I save a file directly to it.

Using a local address or VPN address the error is the same. (Only in visual studio)

My network drive is mapped using a user and password. Which is different from my Windows session.

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions on how to resolve this issue? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. When I gave permissions in the directory I ran the command chmod 770 instead of 775. That was causing the issue. Only when I opened it as a folder in Vscode and Sublime. It seems to me that when Vscode and Sublime are opened as a project, they execute something in the directory which is obviously blocked by execution in Ubuntu Samba with permission 770.